# Why can't Stack Exchange just log me into other sites automatically?

Tags: discussion, login, linked-accounts

I have 7 or 8 accounts across the Stack Exchange site. When I bring the StackExchange dropdown menu down, it lists all my accounts for each forum and my reputation for each as well. Why, when I click on some of them, do I have to either "Log In" again, or refresh the page when the notification pops up the top saying `Welcome back scrowler, you have been logged in. Please refresh the screen`

I don't want to log in again and again, and I don't want to have to refresh the screen (call me impatient).

**Request:**

- click on one of the SE networks in the drop down
- have the link automatically generate the required authentication cookies required for the site
- continue

**Objective:**

- prevent the need to log in, or refresh the page after automatic login when clicking on a linked SE account

Comment: Hi @LowerClassOverflowian - pretty close, but I don't even think that the network needs to refresh "on successful automatic login" like that post is asking about - if you can show me I'm linked to those other networks, why should I have to worry about being logged in at all?

Comment: *"Seems to me like that authentication process is already done if you're showing the accounts"* The dropdown knows your accounts by looking in the database. It can't set authentication cookies for other domains.

Comment: Well, it should generate those for you before you get sent to the other site. It's even worse on a mobile, I have to go through a four step process to log in to reply here, but I can go straight to stack from the drop down and be logged in (cookies sure, but shouldn't those links compensate for the potential loss of cookies when they know you are who you say you are?)

Comment: I'm aware of that. Maybe the regeneration happens on the domain you're being sent to? Think about it and ignore the technical aspects, some of the data gets carried across but some doesn't. Why not? "Technical reasons." Is there a solution? Of course there is, but everyone here seems too interested in trying to tell me that I'm a knob jockey to think about it.

Comment: Nobody said anything like that, unless there's a deleted comment that I can't see. Anyway, your question will probably be better received if you reword it into a simple feature request without the condescending tone.